# Is there an advantage to linking a shared object library from gcc generated objects with g++?

Tags: gcc, g++, shared-libraries

I came across a project recently that created it's shared object libraries by linking gcc generated object files (using the `CC` gnu makefile macro) with g++.

Aside from (possibly) ensuring the source code is encapsulated inside `#ifdef __cplusplus / extern "c" { / #endif` constructs to avoid name mangling problems, is there any reason why this would be ... better?

Comment: That's two pretty big problems already. Linking with the appropriate C++ standard library (and having the right include paths for such) would be yet another.

Comment: @Mat It works, was just wondering if there's an advantage.

Comment: @Mat, what do you mean? Using `g++` automatically provides the right paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they only *link* with `g++` then adding preprocessor checks and `extern "C"` is useless, that only affects preprocessing and compilation, at the linking stage that's already done.

They might have wanted to ensure that exceptions could propagate through their C library, but to do that they only need to link to libgcc not libstdc++.

Maybe they just wanted the shared library to depend on libstdc++, so that users of the library would also depend on libstdc++ and wouldn't have to link to it explicitly, although that might not work as they expected.

So in short, no, I can't think of any good reason if all the code is C code and not C++ code.

**However** just because something is compiled with `gcc` doesn't mean it's C code, you can use the `gcc` executable to compile C++ code and it will invoke the C++ front-end (`cc1plus`) instead of the C front-end (`cc1`). If the C++ code uses the standard library then you either need to link with `-lstdc++` **or** use `g++` to link (which automatically links with `-lstdc++`). So maybe the answer is that it's C++ code, and the fact they compiled the objects with `gcc` not `g++` made you think it was C code.

Comment: Your first paragraph sums up my suspicions.   ... And it's all `c` code.